# Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument

Tags: php, mysql

I am a little rusty in PHP after several years without programming with this language.

I am fetching data from an array in mySQL using PHP.

My problem is that at some point I fetch data from a table, using this:

```
$myArray = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
```

but at some point, the data base may be empty, so $myArray will be null or contain no elements.

Then I have to check if a particular string that is generated on-the-fly is on $myArray. If it is, another string must be generated and verified if it already exists on $myArray.

```
$myString = generateString();
if (in_array($myString, $myArray)) {
    $myString = generateString();
}
```

this code gives me this error:

**Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument**

To prevent in_array from running when $myArray is empty I did this:

```
if (count($myArray) > 0) {
    if (in_array($myString, $myArray)) {
        $myString = generateString();
    }
}
```

but count is giving me 1 when the array is empty (?)...

How do I solve that?

just another question: $myString is being modified inside the IF that is already testing it. Is this possible in PHP?

Comment: The `mysql`-extension is outdated and the use is discouraged. Use `MySQLi` or `PDO_MYSQL` instead. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: According to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), you are probably getting `false` back. Can you post the output of `var_dump($myArray)`? On a side note, `mysql_*` are soon to be deprecated, take a look at [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if your query failed, you'll have... wait for it... no array!

So that `in_array` call would give you a warning about `$myArray` not being an array (but `false`).

You need to check your query for errors, and better yet:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Where did you take this box from? Beside that a referece is always good: I want it :D

Comment: http://stackapps.com/q/2116. Comment source code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/3881905